# Why is the Complexheatmap package very slow to draw heatmaps

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, heatmap, complexheatmap

When i use `complexheatmap` package in `Rmarkedown` to draw a heatmap,it's very very slow.

```r
> dim(exp)
[1] 12907   173
> system.time(p <- Heatmap(exp,show_column_names = TRUE, 
+         show_row_names = FALSE,
+         heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "",legend_height = unit(4, "cm")),
+         column_names_rot = -90,
+         row_names_gp =  gpar(fontsize = 4),
+         column_names_gp =  gpar(fontsize = 5),
+         clustering_method_rows = "ward.D2",
+         name = "Scale(exp)",
+         cluster_column_slices = F,
+         cluster_rows = T,
+         heatmap_width = unit(5, "npc"),
+         heatmap_height = unit(7, "npc"),
+         clustering_method_columns = "ward.D2",
+ ))
The automatically generated colors map from the minus and plus 99^th of the absolute values in the
matrix. There are outliers in the matrix whose patterns might be hidden by this color mapping. You
can manually set the color to `col` argument.

Use `suppressMessages()` to turn off this message.
`use_raster` is automatically set to TRUE for a matrix with more than 2000 rows. You can control
`use_raster` argument by explicitly setting TRUE/FALSE to it.

Set `ht_opt$message = FALSE` to turn off this message.
'magick' package is suggested to install to give better rasterization.

Set `ht_opt$message = FALSE` to turn off this message.
   user  system elapsed 
  0.574   0.001   0.636 
> Sys.time()
[1] "2023-03-06 07:19:09 UTC"
> p
> Sys.time()
[1] "2023-03-06 07:22:05 UTC"
>
```

As shown in the above code, the heatmap took about 3 minutes to create.It's been too long for me.
What should I do to make heatmap faster when generating HTML report which use `Rmarkdown(knit)`!

I guess the heatmap quality is too high, I don't need that high quality, low quality heatmap presentation is acceptable for html file, and can greatly reduce the size of the html file.
I am running R version 4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with ComplexHeatmap version 2.8.0.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: You have a 12907 x 173 matrix, sure this takes some time. Maybe try `?heatmap` if it's faster.

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you for your comment and I will check to see if `?heatmap` is faster